# Bug in FormPage / FormFunction using Return inside module

Tags: cloud-deploy

Someone knows why to I need to use `/.Return -> Identity` in the code below?

```
FormPage[
    "code" -> "String"
    , Module[{},
        If[#code!="123", Return["wrong code:" <>#code ]];
        "your code is right: "<>#code

    ]/.Return -> Identity &
]
```

If I didn't add this, I get `Return` in the output.

[image]

Is this a Bug in FormPage / FormFunction ?

Comment: I suspect it is equally likely to be a problem in the design of `Return`. Suggestion: Try using `Return[...,Module]` and see if that improves matters.

Comment: Yes, `Return[...,Module]` solves! Tks Daniel. It seems like a bug so.